# How to get Child Class Object in single step?

Tags: java

I want to create a child class object

more than 100 class extend MasterClass

MasterClass is

```
 public class MasterClass{
  private int key;
  private String value;
  private String description;

  public String getKey()
  {
    return key;
  }

  public void setKey(String key)
  {
    this.key= key;
  }


  public String getDescription()
  {
    return description;
  }

  public void setDescription(String description)
  {
    this.description = description;
  }

  public String getValue()
  {
    return value;
  }

  public void setValue(String value)
  {
    this.value= value;
  }

 }
```

example of other class

```
public class Product extends MasterClass{
  public Product(){ }
 }
public class Customer extends MasterClass{
  private int productKey;
  public Customer (){ }
 public String getProductKey()
  {
    return productKey;
  }

  public void setProductKey(String productKey)
  {
    this.productKey= productKey;
  }

}
```

etc...

i will get a MasterClass object from client, i wanted to type cast that object to respective one

```
if(masterClass instanceof User) {  
  User a_user = (User) a_ masterClass;

} else if(masterClass instanceof Customer) {
  Customer a_customer = (Customer) a_ masterClass;

}
  .
  .//96 else if
  .
  .
  .
  .
  else
  {
   //Create an object
  }
```

if i do this i will end up with 100s of else if.

Please let me know how i can achieve this without else if?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to do with `a_user` after that?

Comment: If you wind up using RTTI (lingo borrowed from C++: run-time type identification, `instanceof`) this much in your code, the best thing to do would be to redesign your code to use polymorphism to accomplish your goals instead.

Comment: @Alex a_user is Persistent Object. All Client Class is Persistent Objects

Answer (score 1):

You need polymorphism.

for example:

```
  public void func(MasterClass m){

     //your if else block;

}
```

**instead of this.You can add func function to MasterClass and override it on each child .Then after you can simply call** : `YourInstance.func();`

```
 public class MasterClass{
         public void func(){};
    }
    public class Customer extends MasterClass{
     @Override
     //implement such on each child
     public void func(){//spesific overrided function for Customer child }
    }

  //then


     public void func(MasterClass m){

             m.func();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

100 child classes? insane. 
I suggest you check if all these child classes is strongly "IS-A" logic relationship with the Master class.

Usually, to avoid if-else ,using polymorphism, java will do run-time check to decide which function to call based on the type of argument.

eg.

```
class Application{

   public static void main(String[] args){
      Application app = new Application();
      ChildClass1 child1 = new ChildClass1();
      ChildClass2 child2 = new ChildClass2();

      app.method(child1); //"ChildClass1's behaviour"
      app.method(child2); //"ChildClass2's behaviour"
   }

  public method(ChildClass1 arg) {
    System.out.println("ChildClass1's behaviour");
  }

   public method(ChildClass2 arg) {
   System.out.println("ChildClass2's behaviour");
  }

   // 98 more...
}
```